# Fatal error: Class 'Company_OrderReports_Block_Adminhtml_Inventoryreport' not found in /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php on line 465

Tags: layout, error, controllers

Anyone have any clue as to what is causing this error in my custom report module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not created a file name `Inventoryreport`.at

```
app/code/yourModuleCodePool/Company/OrderReports/Block/Adminhtml
```

You have called some block just like `$this->getLayout()->createBlock('yourbLockprefix/adminhtml_inventoryreport')`..which call this class which does not exist.